# Adding class Library reference to DNX Core project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, shared-libraries, dnx50

I have created a Asp.Net 5 project with some rest APIs. I have added a reference to another class library. I can see that the reference has been added in the DNX 4.5.2 (MessageQueue)references however it has not been added to the DNX Core 5.0 references.

When I try to pull in the Namespace I'm allowed to use the class but the project wont build as it says that the namespace has not been declared. This is really starting to get frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DNX Core 5.0` is a lightweight version of the framework optimized for cloud. If you do not need to support it just remove from `"frameworks"` in `project.json`.

```
 // comment out or delete.
 "dnxcore50": { }
```